# How can you tell when a java.jms.TopicSubscriber loses its connection to the message broker?

Tags: java, jms

I was experimenting with a TopicSubscriber object today (with ActiveMQ as my message broker and JMS provider).  I found that if I initiated a synchronous receive (with a 2 ms timeout) after establishing a connection, that an exception would be thrown if I stopped ActiveMQ in between establishing the connection to it and initiating the first receive.  But if I did the connect, then a successful receive, then stopped the broker, and then did a second receive, that instead of having an exception thrown on that receive, I consistently just got a null message back - no indication that the connection to the broker was lost - even after waiting a couple of hours.  And then, after restarting ActiveMQ, unless my program closed and reopened its connection to it, none of its receives would work.

I know I can code around this, but I'm wondering if I've missed something as far as knowing how to tell if my connection is lost - please tell me if there's a way, or if this is just a "feature" of ActiveMQ's JMS implementation that I need to code around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using ActiveMQ for a few years, though with queues and not topics, and I've never seen behavior like that. I could see, perhaps, if a connection were interrupted without the broker being able to properly disconnect a consumer, that the consumer might not be aware immediately about the problem. I don't know for sure, but I think that ActiveMQ consumers don't do much talking to the broker after the connection is established. They just wait for messages to be delivered. Still, I'd expect there to be some kind of heartbeat, and on the [OpenWire Format page](http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-wire-formats.html), it does imply that OpenWire has a default 30-second idle time on it. Try doing some network monitoring to see if the consumer ever tries to send anything. If it does and still doesn't recognize that the connection is dead, then there's something fishy going on. Otherwise, it's probably just a matter of finding the right way to do a keep-alive.  The [TCPTransport keepalive](http://activemq.apache.org/tcp-transport-reference.html) etting might be good to investigate, too.

Comment: Thank you, Ryan.  I'm sure part of the problem is the way I shutdown ActiveMQ.  I just pressed CTRL-C and said yes to Terminate it.  I'll see if I do a clean shutdown if things work "better."  FYI, I'm also probably being weird by synchronously grabbing available messages periodically rather than just waiting for them to be delivered asynchronously.  The Javadoc says I get a null message back if there's nothing there.  It's a little ambiguous as to whether or not an exception should be thrown if the broker is down.

Comment: Note I may just connect, grab messages, and disconnect, from now on.  I was trying to maintain the connection through out the polling, but not if the behavior I witnessed occurs. I wish there was a simple way to validate a connection still exists, but I haven't seen one.

Comment: @Dale: If "synchronously grabbing" means consumer.receive() or something like it, you need to know that calling that method doesn't "reach out" to the server when you call it. For efficiency, ActiveMQ delivers messages to consumers in batches (default batch size is 1000, I believe), and they consumers hold it in an internal queue. Calling consumer.receive() just gets an available message from this internal queue. It doesn't hit the server. I find the simplest way to manage JMS stuff is via [Spring JMS](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html).

Comment: Eureka.  I am doing consumer.receive(2).  From what you're saying, I'm seeing what I'm seeing because when I do the first receive it hits the server - hence if the server is down, an exception does get thrown, but when I do the second receive, the logic doesn't bother going to the server, so it doesn't know to throw an exception.  I just get null back.FYI, I tried keepAlive=true this morning, and it made no difference.  I'll just alter my design a little to deal with this kind of situation.  Thank you very much for your help on this.

Comment: @Dale: Glad I could help. I'd be interested to know if you find out any more about the problem.